# Equivalent of Android radio buttons with no popup and one selectable choice?

Tags: java, android

I want to create something similar to a `listpreference` menu item with a single selectable option out of four options. The problem is that descriptions are necessary for each selectable option and they are rather long. Shortening descriptions further isn't an option.

The Android app I'm working on currently uses a custom method for displaying a menu item's summary field. The summary calls an `int` which points to a string reference stored in a different file that displays a string. I tried using `%s` as the summary to update the summary with my selected option but that literally returned "%s". I don't think the current method supports dynamically loading summaries.

My next idea is to create a submenu with four selectable choices (maybe checkboxes?) and only allow one to be chosen. I think this is essentially a `listpreference` menu item but allows more space for separated descriptions. Is there a preferred way to accomplish this? I'm trying to avoid re-writing the original custom method for displaying descriptions as it works well for the rest of the app's menu needs.

EDIT 1: An image will help explain what I want. See [Android sample settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3HOO.jpg). I want to create a section similar to the "embedded frame buffer" section in a submenu except only one of the three options are selectable. This approach will allow me to have more room for separated, long descriptions. Perhaps I'm looking for radio buttons with no popup and one selectable choice? Is this a thing in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly but instead of a list of checkboxes where only one checkbox is checkable use a RadioGroup with Radiobuttons. You can have multiple RadioButtons which you add to a RadioGroup and then only one RadioButton can be selected.

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to Java. I added an edit with an image to make my question clearer.  Perhaps I'm looking for radio buttons with no popup and one selectable choice? Is this a thing in Java?

Comment: Well first of all the GUI elements are part of android studio and not java. Im not sure what you mean by no popup but in a RadioGroup there is always just one choice selectable. Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Comment: After some further reading, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!